# Kinect V1 + Raspberry PI 4B + OpenNI

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, kinect, raspberrypi, openni.launch

has anyone managed to get the combination ROS Melodic + Ubuntu Mate 18.04 + Kinect V1 + Raspberry PI 4B to work using the openni package? When I run the command `roslauch openni_laucn openni.launch` I get the message that no devices were found or no devices connected. However, the Kinect V1 is connected correctly.

**UPDATE:**

Initially I was receiving these error messages when executing the `roslaunch openni_laucn openni.launch` command:

```
[ INFO] [1708470618.618194377]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1708470618.618560766]: 1. device on bus 001:07 is a SensorV2 (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id 'A00364A19758138A'
[ INFO] [1708470618.619640933]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1708470620.043749080]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @ /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-openni-camera-1.11.1/src/openni_device.cpp @ 61 : creating depth generator failed. Reason: USB interface is not supported!
```

So I ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libopenni-sensor-primesense0
```

and then I started receiving this message:

```
[ INFO] [1708476651.638579070]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

When I run the `lsusb` command, Kinect v1 is displayed:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
```

any suggestion?